# find current form and change action url and submit using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

In my JSP, I have different `<form>`s and each `<form>` has `<table>`, `<th>`, `<tr>` and `<td>`. when I click on a `<TH>` tag, we should find the `<form>`, change the action url and submit in JQUERY click() event.

My code is as follows:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th id='th1'>th1</th>
        <th id='th2'>th2</th>
        <th id='th3'>th3</th>
        <th id='th4'>th4</th>
        <thead>
    </table>
</from


<form>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th id='th1'>th1</th>
        <th id='th2'>th2</th>
        <th id='th3'>th3</th>
        <th id='th4'>th4</th>
        <thead>

    </table>    
</from>
```

Here, when I click on `<th id='th1'>`, we should find the `<form>`, change the action url and submit it. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('th').click(function(){
    var $form = $(this).parents('form');
    $form.attr('action', 'new url').submit();
})
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/AZTRq/2/)

Comment: Hi, i did this one, but i am getting alert Stack Overflow at line:0

Comment: @Ravichandra I am sure that that must come from somewhere else in your code.Can you post a link to your page?

Answer (score 1):

say e.g. you have a form

```
<form>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th id='th1'>th1</th>
        <th id='th2'>th2</th>
        <th id='th3'>th3</th>
        <th id='th4'>th4</th>
        <thead>
    </table>    
</from>
```

you can try

```
$("th").click(function(e){   
var thisForm = $(this).closest("form");
thisForm.attr("action","yourAction");
thisForm.submit(); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First take care of the problems in your HTML:

1. Fix your closing `</form>` tags (it's "form", not "from").
2. Give your `<th>` elements unique `id` attributes.

Then something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("th").click(function() {
       $(this).closest("form").attr("action", this.id).submit();
    });

});
```

You don't make it clear what you wanted to set the form's action to, so by way of an example I've set it to be the id of the clicked `<th>` element.

Comment: Hi, i did this one, but i am getting alert Stack Overflow at line:0